# Parameter is missing a value SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have a `SSRS 2005` report with two parameters. The CountID parameter is a queried value (`From query`). I am calling this report from ASP.Net 2.0 using following approach and it works fine.

```
 window.location.href= strRepServer + strReport + "&rc:Parameters=false&rs:ClearSession=true&plantcd=" + strPlantCD + "&CountID=" + strCountID;
```

Note that we are passing only one string value from ASPX page for the parameter CountID. Still it works fine.

Now, I modified the code to use reportviewercontrol using following code. But when the report renders, it says “The 'CountID' parameter is missing a value”.  I have referred following two posts – but it didn’t help. Any idea how to make it work?

1. [Pass Multi value parameter to SSRS from UI](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7eada0e-a6c9-4d58-9bcc-d3387fe1b40d/pass-multi-value-parameter-to-ssrs-from-ui?forum=sqlreportingservices)
2. [Passing a Multi-value parameter to the ReportViewer control](http://forums.asp.net/t/1338302.aspx)

Note:  I understand that if I make the CountID as `non-queried` or making it as textbox will resolve the issue. But I need to make code working without changing the `rdl` file. [Reason being the rdl works fine with previous approach (calling report without reportviewer)]

**CODE**

```
   rvInvalidPackageSKUs.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote

   rvInvalidPackageSKUs.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://myserver/ReportServer/")
   rvInvalidPackageSKUs.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/MyFolder/SubFolder/MyReport"

   Dim rpPlant As New ReportParameter
   rpPlant.Name = "plantcd" 
   rpPlant.Values.Add("23")

   'Dim rpCountID As New ReportParameter
   'rpCountID.Name = "CountID"
   'rpCountID.Values.Add("1")

    Dim rpCountID As ReportParameter
    rpCountID = New ReportParameter("CountID")
    Dim valuesArray As String() = New String() {"x", "y", "z"}
    rpCountID.Values.AddRange(valuesArray)

    Dim paramList As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)
    paramList.Add(rpPlant)
    paramList.Add(rpCountID)

    rvInvalidPackageSKUs.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList)
    rvInvalidPackageSKUs.ServerReport.Refresh()
```

**Parameter in RDL**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By setting "Available values" to "From query", you actually restrict the values that SSRS will accept. I believe that if you'll pass a value that is not in the list, it will just ignore it and then you'll get the "missing value" error.

Did you make sure that the value you're passing exists the "Counts" dataset?

Comment: Can you please tell why it worked fine when I used the url approach (without using reportviewer) ?

Comment: Could you please tell me if the block you commented works? (setting a single value to the "rpCountID" parameter instead of multiple). Additionally, please try using `rpCountID.Values.Add` for each value, instead of `rpCountID.Values.AddRange` for all of them at once. Does it work?
BTW, I would still make sure that **all** the values you apply to the parameter do exist in the dataset. From my experience, it is quite common that a single value messes up the entire thing.

Comment: Since you mentioned that when using the url approach you only pass a single value, my guess is that either the parameter is not accepting the values because of the method in which you assign them, or because there's a single value which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

ReportParameter rptParameter = default(ReportParameter);
rptParameter = new ReportParameter("Here Put The Parametrs Name", "Here Put the Column Name/Value getting from Database");

rptViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParameter);